# Is foreachRDD executed on the Driver?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am trying to process some XML data received on a JMS queue (QPID) using Spark Streaming. After getting xml as DStream I convert them to Dataframes so I can join them with some of my static data in form of Dataframes already loaded.
But as per API documentation for foreachRdd method on DStream:
it gets executed on Driver, so does that mean all processing logic will only run on Driver and not get distributed to workers/executors.

API Documentation

> `foreachRDD(func)`
>
> The most generic output operator that applies a
> function, func, to each RDD generated from the stream. This function
> should push the data in each RDD to an external system, such as saving
> the RDD to files, or writing it over the network to a database. Note
> that the function func is executed in the driver process running the
> streaming application, and will usually have RDD actions in it that
> will force the computation of the streaming RDDs.

Answer (score 13):

> so does that mean all processing logic will only run on Driver and not
>   get distributed to workers/executors.

No, *the function itself* runs on the driver, but don't forget that it operates on an `RDD`. The inner functions that you'll use on the `RDD`, such as `foreachPartition`, `map`, `filter` etc will *still run on the worker nodes*. This **won't** cause all the data to be sent back over the network to the driver, unless you call methods like `collect`, which do.

Comment: Well, this is so confusing, "No, the function itself runs on the driver, but don't forget that it operates on an RDD", suppose `rdd.foreachRDD(func)` is called, and this `func` function writes data to a redis via a global var `redis_client`, that means `func` refers to `redis_client`, so Q is: will any exception be raised in `foreachRDD` call, since `redis_client` is not serializable.

Comment: @loganecolss I agree, the semantics of execution are complicated. `rdd.foreachRDD` executes `func` on the executors. If `func` *captures* `redis_client` via closure, you'll get a `TaskNotSerializable` exception. If the instance of `redis_client` is allocated inside `func`, you'll be fine.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Quoting your comment: _rdd.foreachRDD executes func on the executors._


From the [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#output-operations-on-dstreams), `foreachRDD` executes `func` on the **Driver**. `foreach`, `foreachPartition` runs on **Executors** though.

Comment: @CᴴᴀZ The operation on the entire `RDD` has to happen on the driver side, but any operation you do on the `RDD` itself, i.e. `foreach` or `foreachPartition` is ran on the executors. That was my intention.

Comment: The very first word of this answer is wrong. The answer is YES. -1 from me, sorry.

Comment: @hey_you But thats incorrect :) He's not asking about where the function is run, he's asking where the processing logic happens.

Answer (score 10):

To make this clear, if you run the following, you will see "monkey" on the driver's stdout:

```
myDStream.foreachRDD { rdd =>
  println("monkey")
}
```

If you run the following, you will see "monkey" on the driver's stdout, and the filter ***work*** will be done on whatever executors the `rdd` is distributed across:

```
myDStream.foreachRDD { rdd =>
  println("monkey")
  rdd.filter(element => element == "Save me!")
}
```

Let's add the simplification that `myDStream` only ever receives one RDD, and that this RDD is spread across a set of partitions that we'll call `PartitionSetA` that exist on `MachineSetB` where `ExecutorSetC` are running. If you run the following, you will see "monkey" on the driver's stdout, you will see "turtle" on the stdouts of all executors in `ExecutorSetC` ("turtle" will appear once for each partition -- many partitions could be on the machine where an executor is running), and the work of both the filter and addition operations will be done across `ExecutorSetC`:

```
myDStream.foreachRDD { rdd =>
  println("monkey")
  rdd.filter(element => element == "Save me!")
  rdd.foreachPartition { partition =>
    println("turtle")
    val x = 1 + 1
  }
}
```

One more thing to note is that in the following code, `y` would end up being sent across the network from the driver to all of `ExecutorSetC` for each `rdd`:

```
val y = 2
myDStream.foreachRDD { rdd =>
  println("monkey")
  rdd.filter(element => element == "Save me!")
  rdd.foreachPartition { partition =>
    println("turtle")
    val x = 1 + 1
    val z = x + y
  }
}
```

To avoid this overhead, you can use broadcast variables, which send the value from the driver to the executors just once. For example:

```
val y = 2
val broadcastY = sc.broadcast(y)
myDStream.foreachRDD { rdd =>
  println("monkey")
  rdd.filter(element => element == "Save me!")
  rdd.foreachPartition { partition =>
    println("turtle")
    val x = 1 + 1
    val z = x + broadcastY.value
  }
}
```

For sending more complex things over as broadcast variables, such as objects that aren't easily serializable once instantiated, you can see the following blog post: https://allegro.tech/2015/08/spark-kafka-integration.html