# Serialization of an object used in foreachRDD() when CheckPointing

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, rdd, avro, kryo

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38526896/is-foreachrdd-executed-on-the-driver) and documentations I've read, Spark Streaming's foreachRDD(*someFunction*) will have *someFunction* itself executed in the driver process ONLY, though if there were operations done on RDDs then they will be done on the executors - where the RDDs sit.

All above works for me as well, though I noticed that if I turn on checkpointing, then it seems like spark is trying to serialize everything in foreachRDD(*someFunction*) and send to somewhere - which is causing issue for me because one of the object used is not serializable (namely schemaRegistryClient). I tried Kryo serializer but also no luck.

The serialization issue goes away if I turn checkpointing off.

Is there a way to let Spark not to serialize what's used in foreachRDD(*someFunc*) while also keep using checkpointing?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there a way to let Spark not to serialize what's used in foreachRDD(someFunc) while also keep using checkpointing?

Checkpointing shouldn't have anything to do with your problem. The underlying issue is the fact that you have a non serializable object instance which needs to be sent to your workers.

There is a general pattern to use in Spark when you have such a dependency. You create an `object` with a lazy transient property which will load inside *the worker nodes* when needed:

```
object RegisteryWrapper {
  @transient lazy val schemaClient: SchemaRegisteryClient = new SchemaRegisteryClient()
}
```

And when you need to use it inside `foreachRDD`:

```
someStream.foreachRDD { 
   rdd => rdd.foreachPartition { iterator => 
       val schemaClient = RegisteryWrapper.schemaClient
       iterator.foreach(schemaClient.send(_))
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Yuval, your suggestion works. One follow up question thou -  regarding this statement "with a lazy transient property which will load inside the worker nodes when needed" - according to this [link] (http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/annotations.html), it states that "Scala provides a @transient annotation for fields that should not be serialized at all" - hence, if schemaRegistryClient is needed on the worker, how could it be sent to the worker (or anywhere else but the driver which is its birthplace) without serialization?

Comment: @howard It isn't sent to the worker. But, don't forget the worker has all the JARs necessary to operate. This means that one an instance is needed, the worker will load the relevant class and create an instance. No need for serialization at all.

Comment: I see, because schemaRegistry is defined as an object variable, so it's in the object definition, hence workers can construct it merely from jar itself. Similar rule apply to checkpointing, it is not serialized and not saved on HDFS, but driver also have the jar and can build it from object definition - so having it as an object definition, @transient annotation and lazy prefix are all necessary for this pattern to work. Thanks again @Yuval!

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov OP asks about `foreachRDD` serializing an object. Is it possible to create a `NonSerializable` object in `foreachRDD`, or does Spark forces the *Serialization* rule across all `foreach*` functions?

Comment: @CᴴᴀZ If you allocate an object in the `foreachRDD` function, than Spark has to make sure its serializable as it has to send it to each partition of the RDD (Of course this assumes you're calling `rdd.foreach` or `rdd.map`). On the other hand inside `rdd.foreachPartition`, if you allocate there than the allocation happens locally per partition, thus no need for serialization.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Since `funcRDD` provided to `foreachRDD` [runs on Driver](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#output-operations-on-dstreams), why does it have to serialize `funcRDD`?

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things here are important:

1. You cannot use this client in the code that is executed on workers (that is inside RDD).
2. You can create Object with transient client field and have it re-created once job is restarted. An example how to accomplish this can be found [here.](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples/streaming/RecoverableNetworkWordCount.scala)
3. The same principle applies to Broadcast and Accumulator variables.
4. Checkpointing persists data, job metadata, and code logic. When the code is changed, your checkpoints become invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Issue might be with checkpoint data, if you changed any thing in your code then you to remove your old checkpoint metadata.